# On Chromebook getConnectionOwnerUid() return -1 (Process.INVALID_UID) on chrome app

Tags: android, chromebook, android-vpn-service

I have a VPN service that uses the `[getConnectionOwnerUid()]`[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getConnectionOwnerUid(int,%20java.net.InetSocketAddress,%20java.net.InetSocketAddress)) function to get the `user ID` (`UID`) of the owner of a network connection. On Android, this function works well for all apps. However, when I try to use it on a Chromebook with the Chrome app, it returns `-1` (`Process.INVALID_UID`).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Is there a different way to get the UID of the owner of a network connection on a Chromebook?

My Chromebook’s details are:

```
ACER CB314 
Model N19Q2 
ARC: 9375475
```

Comment: You should probably mention which device / version of ChromeOS / [Android subsystem](https://chromeos.dev/en/posts/making-android-more-secure-with-arcvm) you are testing on.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that given the reuse of model names with Chromebooks, [code name/board name/base board name](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/) and version of ChromeOS should also be used. Also given that [Android on Chrome has changed over time](https://chromeos.dev/en/posts/making-android-more-secure-with-arcvm) it may be worth [submitting a bug report](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/HEAD/reporting_bugs.md) if reproducible with different VPNs.